# Comparing math operator with string

Tags: javascript

I'm starting at web development and trying to create my first web app, a calculator, but I bumped into a bit of a problem.

I wanted an app where the user wrote the operator of the operation that needs to be performed and then the program would check this operator and run the specified equation. I know how to perform this in Python but I cannot use the same approach in JS in an HTML file.

In Python I would do something like this:

```py
a = 4
b = 4
operator = '+'

if operator == '+':
    print(a+b)
if operator == '-':
    print(a-b)
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't use the same approach in JS? What have you tried so far, and what happened?

Comment: So I've tried to ask the user to input a operator and then tried to compare it with the string of it. 
Here is my current code
```
    function conta(){
        let a = document.getElementById("numero_1");
        let b = document.getElementById("numero_2");
        let c = document.getElementById("operador");
        let resposta = document.getElementById("resultado");
         

        let value_a = Number(a.value);
        let value_b = Number(b.value);
        if (operator == '+'){
            var equation = value_a + value_b
        }
        resposta.value = equation;

Comment: It simply did not return the result anymore. When It was just one operation like a sum, it returned the value. But just form SUM.

Comment: @IMSoP so I just got it to work, I wasn't returing the value to the operator, so the comparison was not being made ! Sorry to bother !

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

So I've got it to work. I was not getting the value as I was trying to compare it.

so I was trying with

```
if (operator == '+'):
   equation = value_b + value_a
```

And it should be

```
if (operator.value == '+'):
   equation = value_b + value_a
```